# FasterXML: POJO serialization to XML. JacksonXml Annotations not working

Tags: fasterxml

I'm serializing a Java POJO to xml and want to change the xml tag names. I can't get this working however, the @JacksonXmlElementWrapper and @JacksonXmlProperty annotations don't get picked up.

Maven pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestJackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The Java classes:

```
  
package com.company;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderItem {

    private String myId = null;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "service")
    private List services = null; //

    public void setId(String myId) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }

    public void setServices(List myServices) {
        this.services = myServices;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return myId;
    }

    public List getServices() {
        return services;
    }
}


package com.company;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Order {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "items")
    private List items = new ArrayList();

    public void setItems(List items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}


package com.company;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderItem {

    private String myId = null;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "service")
    private List services = null; //

    public void setId(String myId) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }

    public void setServices(List myServices) {
        this.services = myServices;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return myId;
    }

    public List getServices() {
        return services;
    }
}
```

The xml produced is not what I expect. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Order>
  <items>
    <items>
      <services>
        <services>service00</services>
        <services>service01</services>
        <services>service02</services>
        <services>service03</services>
        <services>service04</services>
      </services>
      <id>id0</id>
    </items>
    <items>
      <services>
        <services>service10</services>
        <services>service11</services>
        <services>service12</services>
        <services>service13</services>
        <services>service14</services>
      </services>
      <id>id1</id>
    </items>
    <items>
      <services>
        <services>service20</services>
        <services>service21</services>
        <services>service22</services>
        <services>service23</services>
        <services>service24</services>
      </services>
      <id>id2</id>
    </items>
    <items>
      <services>
        <services>service30</services>
        <services>service31</services>
        <services>service32</services>
        <services>service33</services>
        <services>service34</services>
      </services>
      <id>id3</id>
    </items>
    <items>
      <services>
        <services>service40</services>
        <services>service41</services>
        <services>service42</services>
        <services>service43</services>
        <services>service44</services>
      </services>
      <id>id4</id>
    </items>
  </items>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by changing the package of the XMLMapper. Was using:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper
```

Now using:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
```

I create the mapper as so:

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(module);
```

The names of fields can be changed like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "personaldetails")
```